# Autosearch http forms

Tags: javascript

I'm building a robot using an AI platform to help people access government information (in the public domain). Is there a way of populating a html form of an external website using the information the user has provided and submitting and retrieving the information using javascript.

E.g. say the search form is on https://www.governmentportal.com/court-location , take the user's information obtained previously, autofilling the form, using a program to press search and returning the results? An example of such a form is:

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tbody><tr>
<td class="FormLabel">Rental postcode</td>
<td align="left">
<input name="txtPostCode" type="text" maxlength="8" id="txtPostCode"class="txt">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="FormLabel">Tenant's Surname</td>
<td align="left">
<input name="txtSurname" type="text" maxlength="50" id="txtSurname" class="txt">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="FormLabel">Month Deposit Paid</td>
<td align="left">
<select name="ddlDepositDateMonth" id="ddlDepositDateMonth" class="ddl"> <option value="mm">mm</option>
</select><select name="ddlDepositDateYear" id="ddlDepositDateYear" class="ddl">
    <option value="yyyy">yyyy</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td align="left">
<a id="lnkSearch" class="SearchButton" href="javascript:__doPostBack('lnkSearch','')">Search &gt;</a>
</td>
</tr>                                                                                
</tbody></table>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what goal you have and what possibilities those pages give you.

If those websites offer an API, you can easily use `jQuery.ajax` or `axios` for data fetching, passing the user input on.

If they don't offer an API you could send `POST` requests with `curl` (I think PHP supports that out of the box?) or if those sites need Javascript support you can use something like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/).

What you can't do is to kind of automatically fill out forms in front of the users eye. This needs to happen on the server side (unless we are not talking about viewing your page in a browser).

Comment: Thank you. What I'm looking at doing is getting their information and checking their details against online records. In this particular case it is to run a reference check to see if their rental deposit was protected in one of the UK government's deposit protection schemes. Many users don't know if the deposit was protected or which scheme it was protected under.

Comment: Unless they offer an API, I guess you need to build your own API. If those forms don't require Javascript you can easily send `POST`-requests via PHP cUrl for instance.